# ¿alguien sabe como ejecutar consultas MYSQL diferidas en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, crud

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas (Empleados con llave primaria AI y Rol con llave primaria AI y foranea referenciada a la primaria de Empleados) y para no generar inconsistencias en los datos ni en la llave autoincrementable quiero hacer en el mismo PHP:

- la inserción de información a la tabla Empleados
- consultar los campos de la tabla Empleados y mandarlos a una variable
- utilizar las variables consultadas para poblar la tabla de Rol

¿hay alguna forma de ejecutar un query antes que otro? ¿habría alguna otra forma de obtener la primary key autoincrementable de la tabla Empleados para así poder usar directamente las variables en la tabla Rol?

```
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO Empleados(Nombre_Empleados,Username) 
                    VALUES('$name','$username')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query1);

    $queryidempleados = mysql_query("SELECT idEmpleados FROM Empleados WHERE Nombre_Empleados='$name'");

    $querynombre_empleados = mysql_query("SELECT Nombre_Empleados FROM Empleados WHERE idEmpleados='$queryidempleados'");

    $queryusername = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM Empleados WHERE idEmpleados='$idempleados'");

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO Rol(idEmpleados,Nombre_Empleados,Username,ConsultaReportes_empleado) 
              VALUES('$queryidempleados','$querynombre_empleados','$queryusername',
              '$employconsult';)";

    mysqli_query($db, $query2);
```

Comment: Tienes dos BD diferentes o tablas?¿

Comment: son dos tablas, pequeño detalle ñ_ñU

Comment: Puedes consultar por la última key creada en tu tabla para luego realizar la otra consulta. Tal véz está pregunta te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112962/3239070

Comment: Puedes hacer que cuando insertes el **Rol** obtengas su **id** para poder utilizarlo en tu siguiente consulta `mysqli_insert_id($db);`

Comment: lamentablemente "select last_insert_id();" solo funciona en querys ya ejecutados, el detalle es que el PHP interpreta totalmente la sintaxis y funcionalidad de el codigo antes de ejecutarse, y al no detectar que aun no existe el registro manda el codigo de error y se detiene. 

parece que tienes razon Cig, ese es el metodo correcto y voy a usarlo para obtener el ID antes de que sea generado

Comment: Igual no se como funcione esto, pero Cig si publicas tu comentario como respuesta cierro la pregunta. Muchisimas gracias a todos por apoyarme.

Comment: La manera mejor de resolver esto sería a nivel de la base de datos, creando un `TRIGGER` que se ejecutará cada vez que haya una inserción en la tabla `Empleados`. Por ejemplo: `CREATE TRIGGER empleados_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON Empleados 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO Rol (idEmpleados) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
    END;` Lo que pasa es que viendo el `INSERT INTO` de tu código en la tabla `Rol` da la impresión de que no has entendido bien para qué sirven las tablas relacionadas, ¿qué sentido tiene que repitas el nombre del empleado en esa tabla?